# Deploy a Bot Framework solution using Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

We have a Bot Framework solution Virtual Assistant which we would like to deploy via an Azure Pipeline connected to GitHub.

Due to the Virtual Assistant template we need to run a specific PowerShell Script to achieve this but I'm getting stuck with the actual script arguments with Azure CLI.

What would be the best way to achieve this. There is no documentation for deploying the Virtual Assistant using the pipeline.

I've got so far but I'm now getting the error: *ERROR: az bot prepare-deploy: error: argument --proj-file-path: expected one argument*

All I can see is that the publish.ps1 script should get this argument.

Below is the pipeline:

```
# Branch trigger needs changing to master/release etc. 
trigger:
- production-cicd

# # Do not trigger build.
# trigger: none

# Disable PR builds
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy files before publishing script run. 
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Deploy Core Bot
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Bot Subscription Name(xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx)'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/s/botname/botname/Deployment/Scripts/publish.ps1'
    arguments: '-resourceGroup "assistantname-rg" -name "assistantname" -projFolder "."'
```

Comment: The first thing I would check would be your `az cli` version. Is it using the most recent. Not related to VA, but we see _many_ bot deployment issues due to older versions of az cli.

Comment: @Koxzi did you ever solve this?